# Redis to permanent storage migration

Tags: node.js, database, redis, migration

Currently, My web application is on Redis db(all database). it's required more than 4 GB RAM which is cost me a lot.

I want to migrate some part of my application into permanent storage DB(SQL, mongo...)

So, Can anyone tell me which is the best choice(SQL, mongo...)?

Technology stack of my application:
nodejs(express)
angularjs
redis

Answer (score 1):

It really depend on your design. Is your data highly relational? Redis is considered a NoSQL technology so I guess MongoDb would be somewhat similar but implementation will be file-based instead of key-value set. If you need your data to have strong relationship between each data set then SQL family is designed for exactly that, but a lot of work is needed to build the tables first and then separate the data.

Comment: Actually, i want to know which one is an exact match in the a that I have to put minimum efforts and fewer code changes.

Comment: Then definitely MongoDB. It's much easier to integrate Node with Mongo with minimal changes than other SQL styled database. It is still up to you to import the data, so plan some backups before you switch.